# CurlExeception with Guzzle using KeenIO

Tags: laravel-5, guzzle, keen-io

I am building a Laravel (5.1) site which uses KeenIO to do some event tracking. Everything went fine locally (on a mac), so I pushed everything up to my digital ocean droplet through forge to start testing on the server. I delegated the keen events to the Laravel queue service for performance reasons. When I ran the queue:listen command I got this strange error.

```
[Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException]
[curl] 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
   CAfile: {my_local_file_path}/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Resources/cacert.pem
   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs [url] https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/{project_id}/events/users
```

I checked the guzzle source code and it looks like this line is where this path is being set inside of Client.php on line 139.

```
$opts[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = __DIR__ . '/Resources/cacert.pem';
```

**DIR** should be referencing the file path of the server though...so why is it still pointing to my local file path on my mac?????

I tried clearing all the Laravel caches and using every other command I could find. This one has me really stumped, guys. Am I missing something super obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an actual solution...but after running composer update on my local machine a few times and pushing back up to the droplet, everything seems to be working...If anyone could shed light on why this fixed things I'd appreciate it, haha.